# SimpleFramwork XML: Element with Inner Text and Child Elements

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, simple-framework, innertext

I have the following situtation in deserializing xml using SimpleFramework of specific format that cannot be changed...

```
<Question ID="Q1">
    THIS INNER TEXT IS THE ISSUE

    <Criteria Type="Normal" Source="OEM">
        <Value Type="0">45.7</Value>
        <Value Type="100">42.7</Value>
    </Criteria>
    <Criteria Type="Impact" Source="OEM">
        <Value Type="0">45.7</Value>
        <Value Type="100">42.7</Value>
    </Criteria>
    <!-- CRITERIA CAN HAVE ANY NUMBER -->

</Question>
```

and here is the class I wrote for Question

```
@Root (name="Question")
public class Question {

    @Attribute (name="ID") 
    private String id;

    @ElementList (inline=true, required=false)
    private List<Criteria> criteria;

    @Text
    private String text;

    // And their getter and setters...
}
```

Now the issue is that, **I CANNOT GET INNER TEXT...**

Can anybody suggest me the way to do this...???

Comment: I also got similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981182/inner-text-and-child-elements but my case is silghtly different...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `@Text` annotation here, this is only possible if you don't have any child.

> and it [`@Text` annotation] can not appear with the another XML element annotations, such
>   as the `Element` annotation.

*Source: [`@Text` API documentation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Text.html)*

However, you can use a `Converter` to those text. This is a bit tricky, but here's an example:

### `Criteria` class:

```
@Root(name = "Criteria")
public class Criteria
{
    @Attribute(name = "Type")
    private String type;
    @Attribute(name = "Source")
    private String source;
    @ElementList(name = "Values", inline = true)
    private ArrayList<Value> values;



    public Criteria(String type, String source)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.source = source;
        this.values = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private Criteria() { }


    // ...


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Criteria{" + "type=" + type + ", source=" + source + ", values=" + values + '}';
    }


    // Inner class for values - you also can use a normal one instead
    @Root(name = "Value")
    public static class Value
    {
        @Attribute(name = "Type", required = true)
        private int type;
        @Text(required = true)
        private double value;


        public Value(int type, double value)
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
        }

        private Value() { }

    } 

}
```

### `Question` class:

```
@Root(name = "Question")
@Convert( value = Question.QuestionConvert.class)
public class Question
{
    @Attribute(name = "ID", required = true)
    private String id;
    @Element(name = "text")
    private String text;
    @ElementList(inline = true)
    private ArrayList<Criteria> criteria;


    public Question(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.criteria = new ArrayList<>();

        this.text = "This inner text ...";
    }

    private Question() { }


    // ...


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Question{" + "id=" + id + ", text=" + text + ", criteria=" + criteria + '}';
    }



    static class QuestionConvert implements Converter<Question>
    {
        private final Serializer ser = new Persister();


        @Override
        public Question read(InputNode node) throws Exception
        {
            Question q = new Question();
            q.id = node.getAttribute("ID").getValue();
            q.text = node.getValue();

            q.criteria = new ArrayList<>();
            InputNode criteria = node.getNext("Criteria");

            while( criteria != null )
            {
                q.criteria.add(ser.read(Criteria.class, criteria));
                criteria = node.getNext("Criteria");
            }

            return q;
        }


        @Override
        public void write(OutputNode node, Question value) throws Exception
        {
            node.setAttribute("ID", value.id);
            node.setValue(value.text);


            for( Criteria c : value.getCriteria() )
            {
                ser.write(c, node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note all those empty constructors. They are required by simple but you can keep them private. You don't have to implement those inner classes as inner.

The key to the solution is the `Converter` which allows you to use *text* and *child-elements* together. You can use a `Serializer` to write all the `Criteria`-childs.

There are some `toString()` methods, those are only for testing - you can implement them as you need.

**Input XML:**

```
<Question ID="Q1">This inner text ...
   <Criteria Type="Normal" Source="OEM">
      <Value Type="0">45.7</Value>
      <Value Type="100">42.7</Value>
   </Criteria>
   <Criteria Type="Impact" Source="OEM">
      <Value Type="0">45.7</Value>
      <Value Type="100">42.7</Value>
   </Criteria>
</Question>
```

**Example code:**

```
Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy()); // Don't miss the AnnotationStrategy!

Question q = ser.read(Question.class, f);
System.out.println(q);
```

**Output:**

```
Question{id=Q1, text=This inner text ...
   , criteria=[Criteria{type=Normal, source=OEM, values=[Value{type=0, value=45.7}, Value{type=100, value=42.7}]}, Criteria{type=Impact, source=OEM, values=[Value{type=0, value=45.7}, Value{type=100, value=42.7}]}]}
```

Not very beautiful, but it's working! :-)

Ps. Since both methods of the Converter are implemented you also can use this code to serialize a `Question` object.