# How to xml-parsing tag+text in tag (simple-framework)

Tags: java, xml-parsing, tags, simple-framework

**How to xml-parsing tag+text in tag (simple-framework) http://simple.sourceforge.net/resources.php**

I want to print this 
 : xliffTestModel=XliffTestModel [attname=hours, g=%1$s, text=hours!!]

**I can't parse "hours!!"**

[XML]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">

    <string name="hours">
        <xliff:g id="hours">%1$s</xliff:g> hours!!
    </string>

</resources>
```

Here is my code.

[Model]

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name = "resources")
public class XMXliffStringModel {
    @Element(name = "string")
    public XliffTestModel xliffTestModel;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "XMXliffStringModel [xliffTestModel=" + xliffTestModel + "]";
    }

}

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Namespace;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name = "string")
public class XliffTestModel {

    @Attribute(required = false, name = "name")
    public String attname = "";

    @Namespace(prefix = "xliff")
    @Element(required = false, name = "g")
    public String g;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "XliffTestModel [attname=" + attname + ", g=" + g + "]";
    }

}
```

[Main Code]

```
XMXliffStringModel xmXliffStringModel = new XMXliffStringModel();
String path = "C:/Users/SEC/Desktop/strings.xml";
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
try {
    xmXliffStringModel = serializer.read(xmXliffStringModel.getClass(), new File(path));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(xmXliffStringModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner text is a bit tricky, since Simple does not allow text and (child-) elements together. But please see my answer here, how you can solve this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462970/simpleframwork-xml-element-with-inner-text-and-child-elements/17496648#17496648

The key part there is the `QuestionConvert` class.